# как убрать по бокам белые полосы css

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! как можно убрать белые полосы с  картинок [тут ссылка на страничку галереи](http://mafiag.ru/tour2/gallery.php#)

Comment: `padding` уберите и поставьте `margin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

padding-right: 0 && padding-left: 0, если я правильно понял
[image: this]

Comment: да спасибо помогло)

Answer (score 0):

Я так подозреваю, речь идет о тенях.
Уберите свойство box-shadow из Вашего css-файла.

Answer (score 0):

img {
     width: 100%
}
Пробовали?
Так же могут быть padding-right/padding-left у блока с изображением. Код бы видеть...

Comment: А ссылка на сайт **с кодом** не подходит для **видеть**? :)

Comment: Сижу с телефона... Пробовал, но не получается код страницы посмотреть.

Comment: @Other не подходит. Минимальный, воспроизводимый пример кода должен быть в самом вопросе.

Comment: @Regent, поэтому я и поставил голос на закрытие. Но всё же...

Answer (score -1):

Когда нужно подогнать изображение под размер блока я использую

```
 div { background: cover }
```